# I'm trying to get a rest resource to a python server with Ionic 3

Tags: python-2.7, rest, flask, ionic2, ionic3

How to title I'm trying to get a rest resource from a server.In particular I must post some data to the server(user and password) and If the request is successfull I simply print "Success" otherwise "error".When I make the request my server answer me with a code 200(which make me think that everything has come to and end) but in my ionic web page I found this error "Failed to load http://127.0.0.1:5000/: Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response".I tried to solve this problem implementing the crossdomain in my server as recommended by several guides but I could not get anything.I also tried to reach the rest resource using in my terminal the comand "curl POST --data "user=0124000769&password=dfgdsfgs" --verbose http://127.0.0.1:5000 " and this return me the right result so I think my server is working fine.To implement the user interface I'm using Ionic 3 framework.Thank you all in advance.Excuse me for my English.This is my code in Ionic:

**login.ts:**

```
    @Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'login.html'
})
export class LoginPage {
  private mat:string;
  private pass:string;


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public http: Http) {}


  postRequest(){
      var headers = new Headers();
      headers.append("Accept","application/json");
      headers.append("Content-Type","application/json");
      headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
      let options = new RequestOptions({headers:headers});

      let postParams = {
        mat:this.mat,
        pass:this.pass
      };

      this.http.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/",postParams,options).subscribe(data=>{
        console.log("OK")},error2 => {
        console.log("Error")
      });

  }

}
```

**login.html:**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Login Page
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding id="page1">
  <form id="page-form2">
    <ion-item id="page-input3">
      <ion-label>
        Matricola
      </ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" placeholder="" [(ngModel)]="mat" name="matricola"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item id="page-input4">
      <ion-label>
        Password
      </ion-label>
      <ion-input type="password" placeholder="" [(ngModel)]="pass" name="password"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  </form>
  <button id="page-button2" ion-button color="positive" block (click)="postRequest()">
    Login
  </button>
</ion-content>
```

**This is the code of my server**
**My rest Resource:**

```
@app.route('/',methods=['POST','OPTIONS'])
@crossdomain(origin='*')
def login():
    username = request.get('mat')
    password = request.get('pass')
    s = Scraper(username, password)
    return jsonify(s.login())
```

**My crossdomain:**

```
def crossdomain(origin=None, methods=None, headers=None, max_age=21600,
                attach_to_all=True, automatic_options=True):
    """Decorator function that allows crossdomain requests.
      Courtesy of
      https://blog.skyred.fi/articles/better-crossdomain-snippet-for-flask.html
    """
    if methods is not None:
        methods = ', '.join(sorted(x.upper() for x in methods))
    if headers is not None and not isinstance(headers, basestring):
        headers = ', '.join(x.upper() for x in headers)
    if not isinstance(origin, basestring):
        origin = ', '.join(origin)
    if isinstance(max_age, timedelta):
        max_age = max_age.total_seconds()

    def get_methods():
        """ Determines which methods are allowed
        """
        if methods is not None:
            return methods

        options_resp = current_app.make_default_options_response()
        return options_resp.headers['allow']

    def decorator(f):
        """The decorator function
        """
        def wrapped_function(*args, **kwargs):
            """Caries out the actual cross domain code
            """
            if automatic_options and request.method == 'OPTIONS':
                resp = current_app.make_default_options_response()
            else:
                resp = make_response(f(*args, **kwargs))
            if not attach_to_all and request.method != 'OPTIONS':
                return resp

            h = resp.headers
            h['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = origin
            h['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = get_methods()
            h['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = str(max_age)
            h['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true'
            h['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = \
                "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
            if headers is not None:
                h['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = headers
            return resp

        f.provide_automatic_options = False
        return update_wrapper(wrapped_function, f)
    return decorator
```

**My Login function:**

```
def login(self) :
    result = {'login': '0' }
    url = 'my_url'

    //There is some action to control the data;


    if not value :
        return result
    result['login'] = '1'
    #Codifica 'result' in formato JSON
    return json.dumps(result)
```

Comment: Try to add CORS element to your index page.

Comment: Check out the docs for phone gap: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.0rc1/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use chrome try to use --disable-web-security option.

Use this on terminal:

```
open -n -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app --args --user-data-dir="/tmp/someFolderName" --disable-web-security
```